# Which is the correct derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{-ax}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}^{++}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have a function $f(x)=\sqrt{-ax}$, where $x\in(-K,0)$, and $a\in\mathbb{R}^{++}$. I proceeded to derive $f'(x)$ in two different ways, in each treating $\sqrt{-a}$ and $\sqrt{a}$ as a constant respectively.

**First Way:**
\begin{align}
f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{-a}}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{a}{-x}}\ge 0.
\end{align}

**Second Way:**
\begin{align}
f'(x)=\sqrt{a}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{-x}}(-1)=\frac{-1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{a}{-x}}\le 0.
\end{align}

Which is the correct way?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^{++}$, with the two pluses?

Comment: What are $\sqrt{-a}$ and $\sqrt x$ in the formula $$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{-a}}{2\sqrt{x}}\ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second way is the correct one. But I would do it like this:
$$g(x)=-ax\\g'(x)=-a\\f(y)=\sqrt{y}\\f'(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\\f'(g(x))=\frac{g'(x)}{q\sqrt{g(x)}}=\frac{-a}{2\sqrt{-ax}}$$
In your first method neither $\sqrt x$ or $\sqrt{-a}$ are real numbers.